# Line thickening image filter for preprocessing of scanned digits

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filtering

For a school project I've built a scanner and connected it to matlab. The scanner scans images (16-by-16 pixels) of handwritten digits from 0 to 9. I'm using a principal component analysis in order to classify the scans. Due to the low accuracy of the scanner, I need to preprocess the scans first, before I can actually send them through the recognition machine.

One of these preprocessing-steps is to thicken the lines. So far, I've used a pretty simple averageing filter for this: `H = ones(3, 3) ./ 9`. This bears the problem, that the circular gap of the digits 8 and 9 is likely to be "closed". I enclose a picture of all my preprocessing-steps, where the problem is visible: the image with the caption "threshholded" still shows the gap, but it disappeared after the thickening step.

[image]

My question is: Do you know a better filter for this "thickening"-step, which would not erase the gap? Or do you have an idea for a filter which could be applied after the thickening to produced the desired result? Any other suggestions or hints are also greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I=imread('numberreco.png');
subplot(1,2,1),imshow(I)
I=rgb2gray(I);
BW=~im2bw(I,graythresh(I));
 BW2 = bwmorph(BW,'thin');
 I1=double(I).*BW2;
subplot(1,2,2),imshow(uint8(I1))
```

[image]

The gap is kept, and you can start from here...

Answer (score 1):

Not a very general answer, but if you have the Image Processing Toolbox, and your system doesn't depend on having multiple grey levels, then converting to binary images and using the 'thicken' operation from [`bwmorph()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html) should do exactly what you want.

Thinking a bit harder, you could also use a suitably thickened binary image as a mask to restore holes - either just elementwise multiply it with the blurred greyscale image or, for more flexibility:

- invert it to form a background/holes mask
- remove the background with [`imclearborder()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/imclearborder.html) to leave just the holes
- optionally dilate the mask
- use as a logical index to clear the 'hole' areas of the blurred/brightened greyscale image.

Even without the morphological steps you can use a mask to artificially reintroduce the original holes later, e.g.:

```
bgmask = (thresholdedimage == 0);  % assuming 0 == background
holes = imclearborder(bgmask);
... % other processing steps
brightenedimage(holes) = 0;  % punch holes in updated image
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Unfortunately, a binary image is not an option, as I need multiple grey levels.